# Angular - multiple promises and iteration - how to get the result

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, angular-promise

Ok I'm new to JavaScript programming and I'm really struggling with the async stuff.  I have tried to show my example below:

**Controller**

```
$scope.handleClick = function(stuff) {
    var promise = fetchOtherStuffs(stuff.id1);
    var promiseTwo = fetchOtherStuffs(stuff.id2);

    $q.all([promise, promiseTwo]).then(function(data) {
        // fails because data is undefined
        console.log(data[0].length);
        console.log(data[1].length);
    }); 
 };

var fetchOtherStuffs = function(stuffId) {
    return $http.get('http://localhost/myapi/stuff/' + stuffId)
        .then(function(theStuffs) {
            var promises = [];

            for (var i = 0; i < theStuffs.data.length; i++) {
                var otherStuffId = theStuffs.data[i].otherStuffId;
                promises.push( 
                $http.get('http://localhost:8085/myapi/otherstuff/' 
                     + otherStuffId));
            }

            $q.all(promises).then(function(data){
                var result = [];

                for (var i = 0; i < promises.length; i++) {
                    result.push(data[i].data[i]);
                }

                // this works and the data count is as expected
                console.log('returning: ' + result.length);            
                return result;
        });               
  });           
};
```

So I need to:

- call `myapi/stuff`
- take the result of that call (which can be many Objects) and call the `/myapi/otherstuff` for each of those Objects
- return all of those Objects from *otherstuff* back to the *handleClick* method

I really don't know how to implement the *fetchOtherStuffs* method so the promise is returns actually returns a value when it's needed in the *handleClick* method.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Should be `return $q.all(promises).then(function() {...})`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot a small little `return` in the `then` callback after getting `myapi/stuff`:

```
function fetchOtherStuffs(stuffId) {
    return $http.get('http://localhost/myapi/stuff/' + stuffId)
    .then(function(theStuffs) {
         …
         return $q.all(promises).then(function(data){
//       ^^^^^^
             …
             return result;
         });
    });
}
```

Also, I'm not sure whether accessing an `[i]` property twice in

> ```
> for (var i = 0; i < promises.length; i++) {
>     result.push(data[i].data[i]);
> }
> ```

is correct, but that of course depends on the format of the data.

Comment: +1 ... The other downvote seems like it was retaliatory.

Comment: thanks a lot - i will go home tonight with a print out of some promise blogposts so i understand a little better. and now i've changed the code i only need data[i] too, as you suggest.

Comment: If you only use `.push(data[i])` (and not `data[i].data.…` or so) you can omit that whole `.then()` callback (if you don't care about the logging), as `data == result` :-)